# Vector of vectors , Separating different values from array

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to separate values from an 2d array. All i need to do is to store all indexes of fields with certain values.

For example i may have an array which has 3 cells with value 1 and 10 fields with value 2.
I tried to create 1 vector which stores all indexes for value 1 and the other one that stores all indexes for value 2 .

here's a code I've been trying to write , but it doesnt seem to wrok

void searchForGrains(Cell **tab, int _size){

```
storage.push_back(tab[0][0]);
Point p(0,0); // Point refers to array indexes
storage[0].points.push_back(p);

for(int i=0 ; i<_size ; ++i){
    for(int j=0 ; j<_size ; ++j){
        int counter = 0;

        for(unsigned int k=0 ; k<storage.size() ; k++){

            if(tab[i][j].value == storage[k].value){
                Point pp(i,j);

                storage[k].points.push_back(pp);
            }
            else
                counter++;
        }
            if(counter == storage.size())
                storage.push_back(tab[i][j]);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm afraid I'm baffled by your explanation of what you want this code to do. Here's the thing 'it doesn't work' doesn't tell anybody anything. Say what the input to your function is, what you expect the output to be, and what the output actually is. And try and explain what these cells and fields that you are talking about are.

Comment: sorry,I deleted some part of explanation by mistake. So as input i have an array(2d). Each field of that array has a value. As output i would like to get all indexes of fields with for example value= 1 in one vector, all indexes of value=2 in other vector and so on, so basicly i would like to store all indexes for each value in separated vectors

Comment: OK got it (I think). Next thing is the types of the variables involved, how have you declared storage for instance.

Comment: ok so vector <Cell> storage; Cell is a class which has a value and inside that class i also have an vector <Point> points that stores an indexes for each cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a pretty simple logic error. The problem is that when you find a new value although you add a new entry to the storage vector you don't add the point where you found the new value. Except for the one at 0,0 which you made a special case, but you don't need to do that. Try this instead

```
void searchForGrains(Cell **tab, int _size)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<_size ; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0 ; j<_size ; ++j)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            for(unsigned int k=0 ; k<storage.size() ; k++)
            {
                if(tab[i][j].value == storage[k].value)
                {
                    Point pp(i,j);
                    storage[k].points.push_back(pp);
                }
                else
                    counter++;
            }
            if(counter == storage.size())
            {
                storage.push_back(tab[i][j]);
                Point pp(i,j);
                storage[storage.size() - 1].points.push_back(pp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No doubt this could be made more efficient but I think it works.